# calculate balance with window function on union select

Tags: mysql, union, window-functions

I have 2 following tables in MySQL 8:

Fiddle URL: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fejdb5mcCm4TUFDacU3R3M/0

**Table1**

```
SELECT * FROM table1
```

| Id | Credit | Debit | Company |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 200 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 100 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 10000 | 0 | 2 |
| 7 | 50 | 0 | 1 |

and **Table2**

```
SELECT * FROM table2
```

| Id | Credit | Debit | Company |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 50 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 100 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 50 | 1 |
| 7 | 0 | 30000 | 2 |
| 8 | 0 | 200 | 1 |

I would like to generate a **Balance** column as follows on a union select for **company=1**, it means balance is: **last row balance+ credit - debit**

```
SELECT id, credit, debit, company, SUM(credit - debit) OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS balance FROM (
SELECT id, credit, debit, company FROM table1 
UNION ALL
SELECT id, credit, debit, company  FROM table2  
) AS u WHERE company=1
```

| Id | Credit | Debit | Company | Balance | Correct Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 0 | 1 | 100 | 100 |
| 1 | 0 | 50 | 1 | 50 | 50 |
| 2 | 0 | 100 | 1 | -150 | -50 |
| 2 | 200 | 0 | 1 | 100 | 150 |
| 3 | 0 | 50 | 1 | 150 | 100 |
| 4 | 100 | 0 | 1 | 50 | 200 |
| 7 | 50 | 0 | 1 | 150 | 250 |
| 8 | 0 | 200 | 1 | -150 | 50 |

The results of the balance are incorrect (I have added the correct balance manually),
what is wrong with my approach and how can I solve it?

DDLs:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `credit` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `debit` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

/*Data for the table `table1` */

insert  into `table1`(`id`,`credit`,`debit`,`company`) values 
(1,100,0,1),
(2,200,0,1),
(4,100,0,1),
(5,10000,0,2),
(7,50,0,1);

CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `id` int(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `credit` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `debit` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

/*Data for the table `table2` */

insert  into `table2`(`id`,`credit`,`debit`,`company`) values 
(1,0,50,1),
(2,0,100,1),
(3,0,50,1),
(7,0,30000,2),
(8,0,200,1);
```

Comment: Can you update your post with an explanation of how you compute values from your fields in your own words? Additionally can you explain where id 7 and 8 come from with respect to the sample input tables you shared?

Comment: @lemon Thanks for your time and consideration. I have updated table 1 and table 2 to correspond correctly to ids, and also I have updated the union table with the **Correct Balance** field. balance is=last row balance+ credit - debit

Comment: If an id can be found in both tables (as happens for id=1 and id=2), how do you choose which transaction happens first? Is priority given to table 1 (as for id=1) or to table 2 (as for id=2) or does it follow some other rule?

Comment: @lemon I got what you mean, if both ids are the same, actually there is no difference but we can say table2 has priority in showing and calculation

Comment: I have added DDLs as well

Comment: Fiddle URL: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fejdb5mcCm4TUFDacU3R3M/0

Comment: There's no way to discern the order within each ID; which appears important. in one case you want T1 first (ID 1) , in another t2 first (ID 2). Given this I can't see how to discern the order to calculate the running total. Attempt - https://dbfiddle.uk/PevKAOQU  is there by chance a date/time involved somewhere which we could use?  like a transaction date/time?

Comment: If table2 has priority, you should change your expected output to reflect that consistently.

Comment: @xQbert, thanks for your time and consideration, there is a date field in the original tables but maybe they credit and debit on the same date (credits are in table1 and debits are in table2). I liked you solution, let me implement it and get back to you

Comment: @xQbert, Thanks it is working as expected. How can I mark your answer as the correct one?

Comment: @MehranIshanian  Lemon really had the initial idea I didn't see it in comments before.  I can post the results as an "answer" but your question isn't correct for that as the answer.  If they debit/credit on same day is there a timestamp on the field? keep in mind simetimes you see just "date" even though behind the scenes it's a date time.

Comment: it really takes a community sometimes to figure things out.  Maybe you want to consider all payments then all credits if done on the same day.  THis way someone doens't "Overdraw" Some Banks process payments before deposits so they "collect" fees for bounced checks even though money was in the account; just that they processed in an unexpected order.

Comment: Dear @lemon, your advice was amazing and useful, thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is we have no way to discern in what order the ID's should be placed to calculate the running total.

We could do something like this where we control which table we use first; but a better approach would be to use a transaction date/time field so we can order by it after ID thus giving you the true order of events.

Lemon asked a similar question earlier in comments, I just showed how this could be implemented and why we struggle with the order in your expected results.  Since your expected results do not match the results of this; reconsider your expected results.  Either indicate order isn't important or identify how we can order (by t1 or t2 first.., or by a datetime field undefined following ID...)

```
SELECT id, credit, debit, company, SUM(credit - debit) OVER (partition by company ORDER BY id, src) AS balance FROM (
SELECT id, 't1' src, credit, debit, company FROM table1 
UNION ALL
SELECT id, 't2' src, credit, debit, company  FROM table2  
) AS u WHERE company=1
```

Comment: Thanks again @xQbert, what is the use of **partition by company** on the over statement?

Comment: Just Incase you don’t filter by a company in the where clause. It ensures the calculation doesn’t include multiple companies. Remove where clause with multiple companies and you’ll see

Comment: Assuming table1, table2 have multiple companies, remove your where clause for company = 1 or do an In for multiple companies.  without the partition the summing will occur across companies.  Maybe that's what you want but given you limit by 1 company here, I figured you would not want to sum across companies in the situation you returned multiple companies.